# Read Bookmarks in android failing on real device

Tags: android

I am reading the bookmarks from the browser in my app. 
It is working on the Emulator in the computer, but when I am running the app on a real device it is crashing.

First of all I am filling a ListView like this:

`String[] proj = new String[]{Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};

String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK;

myCursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, sel, null, null);


        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txtTitle, R.id.txtUrl};

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_view_row, myCursor, proj, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        bookMarksListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewBookMarks);

        bookMarksListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

And that is working on the Emulator. 
The emulator is running Android 2.3.3

And the real device is running android 4.0.4

I tought that Android 4.0.4 can run 2.3.3? 
Any advice on how I should get this to work?

I want the app to be able to run on devices from 2.3.3 up to 4.0

Comment: I think the reason is that your emulator is rooted and phone NO.

Comment: And is there an way around, if that is the case? I got the permission in the manifest so i can read bookmarks.... But still, do  you really need a rooted phone to do this?